# Accessing arrays created by explode function in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner in PHP and mySQL. I pass a string to the PHP with AJAX and then I split the string after new lines. Later I assign each element in the array to a variable. I want to pass the variables to mySQL database.

Please assume:

```
$q = "John \n Doe \n 07589334009 \n john.doe@john.com";
```

Here is my attempt:

```
$date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');

$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $q);
$name = $arr[0];
$surname = $arr[1];
$phone = $arr[2];
$email = $arr[3];



$sql = "INSERT INTO `database`.`myTable` (`Name`, `Surname`, `Phone`, `Email`, `reg_date`, `Valid`) 
VALUES ('$name' , '$surname', '$phone', '$email', '$date', '1');";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

When I check my database I only see "JohnDoe07589334009john.doe@john.com" in the name column. Apart from that name and valid are columns are okay.

Comment: `PHP_EOL` does not necessarily equal `\n`. Use a literal `\n` in your call to `explode()`.

Comment: Or use `preg_split` to handle the different kinds of new line formats.

Comment: To add on to what @JohnConde mentioned, [the docs for `PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) specifically mention that it is platform specific. *"The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform."*

Comment: You really need to escape any user input before trying to insert it into a database query. Use prepared statements.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Use explode("\n", $text); or preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $text); or explode(PHP_EOF, $text);

Comment: I've tried \n as well, it doesn't work. Also @MarcB, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to do it like

```
    $arr = explode("\n", $q);
    $name = $arr[0];
    $surname = $arr[1];
    $phone = $arr[2];
    $email = $arr[3];
```

Explode using \n and remove spaces from it after exploding

Answer (score 0):

`PHP_EOL` is not necessary to be `"\n"`, it's a constant holding the line break character used by the server platform. Therefore, it can be used when you are writing to the file system such as logs but not as an equivalent to `"\n"`.

So, you have to replace `PHP_EOL`  with `"\n"`